# Save an email to a case's Activity History

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage, activityhistory

**Context**
I have a JS button in the case layout that sends an email to the contact via Apex.

**Problem**
How can I save that sent email to the case's Activity History?

I've found similar questions, like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/how-can-i-save-an-email-to-a-case), but it wasn't replied, and I haven't been able to find any other useful information.

I've tried:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
mail.setWhatId(caseId);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

but it just saves it to the contact, which is not what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that, Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId and it is mandatory.

Ideally, if you want to send an email to Contact then put `ContactId` as `targetObjectId`

So, if you don't like to put Contact then use `UserId` as `targetObjectId`.

Moreover, if you have activity on Contact it will also be reflected under Account.

Following code save the email under ActivityHistory of Case, Contact and Account.

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage theMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

theMessage.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);

theMessage.setTargetObjectId(this.myCase.ContactId);

List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
toAddress.add(this.myCase.Contact.Email);
theMessage.setToAddresses(toAddress);
theMessage.setWhatId(this.myCase.Id); 
theMessage.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
messages.add(theMessage);    
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

Comment: I know, but my question is how can I save it under the case's ActivityHistory, not the contact's.

Comment: this will save under ActivityHistory of Case, Contact and Account

Comment: Oh, darn, the combination of the three! That was so stupid of me, I tried combining them, but never thought of using the three properties at the same time. True. Thanks a lot, Santanu!

Comment: OK but we often have Cases without any Contact. So the Contact Id is not available.  Is there a way to save a record of the outgoing email on the Case (WhatId)?